# Elementor Theme Builder - Add Custom Condition for Product Archive

Tags: woocommerce, elementor

I am trying to add a custom condition to Elementor's Theme builder for Product Archive.
I am working with their documentation (https://developers.elementor.com/docs/theme-conditions/)
And I am able to add the condition to the Archive type, however cant seem to find how to  have this condition only to the 'Product Archive'

I thought it might be  related to this:

```
$conditions_manager->get_condition( 'archive' )->register_sub_condition( new My_Custom_Condition() );
```

and tried changing it to 'product-archive' and 'product_archive' like so:

```
$conditions_manager->get_condition( 'product_archive' )->register_sub_condition( new My_Custom_Condition() );
```

But that resulted in an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function register_sub_condition() on bool
```

This is my Custom Condition:

```
class My_Custom_Condition extends \ElementorPro\Modules\ThemeBuilder\Conditions\Condition_Base {   
/**
     * Get condition group type.
     *
     * Retrieve condition group type.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public static function get_type() {
        return 'archive';
    }

    /**
     * Get condition name.
     *
     * Retrieve condition unique ID.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_name() {
        return 'custom_name';
    }

    /**
     * Get condition label.
     *
     * Retrieve condition label.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_label() {
        return esc_html__( 'MY CONDITION', 'elementor-custom-condition' );
    }
    
    /**
     * Set condition Options
     *
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access protected
     * @return string
    */
    protected function register_controls() {
        $this->add_control(
            'custom_condition',
            [
                'section' => 'settings',
                'label' => __( 'Custom' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT,
                'options' => ['1','2','3'],
            ]
            );
    }
    

    

    

    /**
     * Check condition.
     *
     * Validate  condition to ensure it complies with certain rules.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     * @return bool
     */
    public function check( $args ) {
        
        
        return true;
    }

}
```

Any Help will be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, figured it out, and  as always, quite simple  (-:

```
$conditions_manager->get_condition( 'product_archive' )
```

It resulted in an error due to priority issue of the action. when my function loaded the Elementor Woocommerce Module was not yet loaded, changing the action priority to a higher one solved this and the  product_archive condition is known.

I hope this will help others.

```
add_action( 'elementor/theme/register_conditions', 'my_custom_theme_conditions', 100 );
```

For reference, the condition ids to be used in `$conditions_manager->get_condition( $id )`:

| Type | `$id` |
| --- | --- |
| Single Product: | `'product'` |
| Product Archive: | `'product_archive'` |